# Google Spreadsheet Custom Function: Too many scripts running

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I am trying to create a custom method in Google Spreadsheet. I have the following method to replace the missing WEEKNUM method. (I leave to second parameter in order to allow upload of excel files.)

```
function WEEKNUM(inDate, dummy){
  return Utilities.formatDate(inDate, "GMT", "w");
}
```

I call in method in approximately 400 rows twice (800 times) in one spreadsheet. Some of the formulas complete however for other I get this error message.

```
error: There are too many scripts running simultaneously for this Google user account.
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this? I understand 800 executions it a lot but not anymore than would be expected of built in functions. I know there are alternative ways to calculate the week number (such as `=LEFT(TEXT(A2; "w d"); 2)`) however I want to know if it is even possible to create custom formula functions that wont be subjected to this invisible ceiling.

Thank you in advanced for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Have you custom function receive a range and output an array. No need to use an arrayformula, which also wont work on a custom function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an ArrayFormula? In your spreadsheet, instead of having 800 calls to:

`=WEEKNUM(-cell-, -dummy-)`

in cells A1 to B400, try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKNUM(A1:B400, -dummy-))`

in cell A1.